# How to get product group details in WHMCS invoice template file invoicepdf.tpl?

Tags: php, templates, invoice, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I am customising WHMCS invoice template using `invoicepdf.tpl`. It is a PHP script basically arrange data in HTML format and convert it to PDF. I can only see client info and invoice details in that file. How can I take product group details there?

Comment: have to read this document ? Link :- http://docs.whmcs.com/Products_and_Services

Comment: That describes how to add products via GUI. Not customisation or programming related. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a whmcs invoice hook( https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/invoices-and-quotes/ ). For example:

- If you want to only customize the way it is displayed https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/invoices-and-quotes/#viewinvoicedetailspage .
- If you want to modify the invoice when created https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/invoices-and-quotes/#invoicecreation .

Then in the hook you can request the data you want from tblproductgroups or any other table if needed.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
add_hook("InvoiceCreationPreEmail", 1, "invoice_productgroup");

function invoice_productgroup($vars)
{
   $result = full_query("SELECT id, description, (SELECT (SELECT (SELECT tblproductgroups.name FROM tblproductgroups WHERE id = tblproducts.gid) FROM tblproducts WHERE id = tblhosting.packageid) FROM tblhosting WHERE id = tblinvoiceitems.relid) AS groupname FROM tblinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceid='".$vars['invoiceid']."' AND type='Hosting';");

   while($data = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
       if($data['groupname'] !== NULL)
           update_query("tblinvoiceitems", array("description" => $data['groupname']." - ".$data['description']), array("id" => $data['id']));
}
```

https://whmcs.community/topic/126837-product-group-in-invoice-item-description/